# pstats print_stats() throws error TypeError: descriptor 'write' requires a '_io.StringIO' object but received a 'str'

Tags: python-3.x, profiling, stringio

I want to write profiler decorator as in the example of official documentation of cProfiler. But I get TypeError.

I have debugged and in pstats module this line throws the exception:

```
print(indent, self.total_calls, "function calls", 
end='',file=self.stream).
```

Here self.stream comes as IoString object.

import cProfile, pstats, io

```
def profile(fnc):
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        pr = cProfile.Profile()
        pr.enable()
        ret_val = fnc(*args, **kwargs)
        pr.disable()
        s = io.StringIO
        sort_by = 'cumulative'
        ps = pstats.Stats(pr, stream=s).sort_stats(sort_by)
        ps.print_stats()
        # ps.dump_stats('results')
        print(s.getvalue())
        return ret_val
    return inner
```

> File "/usr/lib/python3.5/pstats.py", line 336, in print_stats
>       print(indent, self.total_calls, "function calls", end=' ', 
>       file=self.stream) TypeError: descriptor 'write' requires a '_io.StringIO' object but received a 'str'

Comment: Well "s" has nothing to stream to the stats. Try using `s = io.StringIO("test")`

Comment: I also see the examples use `StringIO.StringIO` instead of what you used. https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/426/pstats.Stats

Comment: io.StringIO() without passing arguments also works. thanks.